# Get type of outer class in template

Tags: c++, templates

```
struct Outer {
    struct Inner {
    };
};

template <typename T>
void test()
{
    ??Outer?? foo; // How do I get the type of T's outer class ?
}

test<Outer::Inner>();
```

Inside test() I have a template argument of type T and I want to declare a variable of whatever type is the outer class of T.

I think this should be trivial for the compiler to get that info, but so far couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: why do you need this? Inner class has very weak relationship with outer class, just visibility. You still need an instance of outer class to call its instance members.

Comment: I had a type called Container::iterator and I want to know the type of the const_iterator (Container::const_iterator). I don't need this any more, but was still curious enough to ask how it was done.

Comment: In fact, type `Container::iterator` might not be an inner class of the container. For example `std::vector<T>::iterator` is often a simple `T*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't be done. There is indeed much information available to the compiler that cannot be easily used in a metaprogramming context. Ongoing work on adding compile-time reflection to the language might eventually improve this situation, but don't hold your breath.

In the meantime, you'll just have to do it the old-fashioned way.

```
struct Outer {
    struct Inner {
        typedef Outer outer_class;      
    };
}
```